# Google Analytics tracking wrong urls

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics. It is tracking some urls which do not event exist in my site.

For example: if the site is abc.com, I can see urls like

/xyz/web.php?r=123

I think somebody has added my domain name and setup locally and implemented analytics. any way to stop unknown hits in google analytics.

Comment: Have you considered adding filters to include only your domains?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your applications is using some kind of url transformation example `/xyz/123` to `/xyz/web.php?r=123`
and tracking code url is inserting like this

```
ga('send', 'event', 'email', <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>);
```

in php requested URL can differ from that you are entering in address bar

I recomment to use `document.URL`

```
ga('send', 'event', 'email', document.URL);
```

this will insert actual URL you see in your browser address bar

Answer (score 0):

You can check by selecting hostname as a second dimension - if anything shows up except your domain name then see MisterPhilipps comment, you can create an "include" filter in the view settings that dismisses data that isn't from your domain (goto filters, include, hostname eq yourdmain.com. Filters are destructive, so keep an unfiltered profile as backup).

However GA will track the url from the browsers address bar regardless of if it points to an existing site. So if possible check if these are 404 pages.

A possible scenario is that somebody tried to install an exploit on your server and now checks if he can execute the exploit code by calling it via an url, or tries to find an unpatched security issue - this is especially worth checking if you use one of the more common PHP based CMS (Wordpress, Drupal etc) where "prefabricated" exploits exist (the fact that somebody checks for malware does not necessarily mean there is actually a problem, though).